# Adding MenuItems in many Pages in Windows Phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to add menuItems in Windows phone page.  I know how to add it in single page.

However is it possible to add a menuItems to couple of pages by assigning it in single page/somewhere (ie Common menuItem (Say Home) which should be appears in all pages)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for a `USER CONTROL`. You can have it to multiple pages. You can have Reference to create it here [Why and how to create a User Control in Windows Phone](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/why-and-how-to-create-a-user-control-in-windows-phone)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper/factory class that creates your base app bar and/or individual menu items.

```
public class AppBarHelper
{
    public static ApplicationBar CreateCommmonAppBar()
    {
        // return app bar with common menu items..etc.
    }

    public static ApplicationBarMenuItem CreateHomeMenuItem()
    {
        // return your menu item
    }
}
```

And then in your pages you could call it like this in the constructor

```
public MainPage()
{
    ApplicationBar = AppBarHelper.CreateCommonAppBar();
}
```